# Ruby, regex to match tabs and replace with 2 spaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone have a regex in ruby that can match and replace a tab with 2 spaces?

Comment: This sounds like you're enforcing some formatting standards on a codebase, spaces instead of tabs. Be warned that doing this via some commit hook script can have negative consequences. The offenders local repositories/working copies will expect to be up-to-date, but diffs with the remote repository will show changes. It's best to do this sort of correction *AFTER* the commit has succeeded.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Couldn't be simpler:

```
str.gsub(/\t/, '  ')
```

Comment: If you have any tab inside strings they will be replaced too so it's not that obvious. The only tabs you're interested in are ones on the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to expand tabs (which is a slightly different task than replacing tabs), then:

```
# This algorithm by Brian Candler (B.Candler@pobox.com) found on the
# org.ruby-lang.ruby-talk mailing list
# http://markmail.org/message/avdjw34ahxi447qk
# Date: 2003-5-31 13:35:09
# Subject: Re: expandtabs

def expand_tabs(s, tab_stops = 8)
  s.gsub(/([^\t\n]*)\t/) do
    $1 + " " * (tab_stops - ($1.size % tab_stops))
  end
end

p expand_tabs("\tfoo", 2)      # => "  foo"
p expand_tabs(" \tfoo", 2)     # => "  foo"
p expand_tabs("\t\tfoo", 2)    # => "    foo"
```

The reason expanding tabs is different than just replacing them is that a tab can represent a different number of characters depending upon which column it appears in.  For example, if the tab stops are every 8 columns, then a tab in the first column should be replaced by 8 spaces, but one in the second column by 7 spaces, one in the third column by 6 spaces, and so on.